# ArcPy Apply Symbology from Layer is not working in script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, layers

I'm trying to apply symbology on all the layers in my TOC that match a certain string. The apply symbology step of the script makes the layers in TOC glitch, which means it gets executed but the layers symbology doesn't change. Whenever I make use of the tool directly on 1 layer it works fine. This is my script.

```
# Tool parameters
symbology = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  
match = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) 


def applySymbols(symbology, match):

    active_map = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("current").activeMap

    layers = active_map.listLayers()
   
    for lyr in layers:  
        if match in lyr.name and lyr.isFeatureLayer:
            #arcpy.AddMessage(lyr.name)
            try:
                arcpy.management.ApplySymbologyFromLayer(lyr, symbology)
                arcpy.AddMessage(lyr.name)
            except:
                arcpy.AddWarning(f"Could not apply to {lyr.name}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    applySymbols(symbology, match)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? have you tried it without the try/except to see if it throws any exceptions?

Comment: @BERA The ArcGIS Pro application is part of the ArcGIS Desktop product. The ArcMap application is not involved because the code uses `arcpy.mp`

Comment: Nevertheless I think when ArcPy is tagged there should be only an ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro tag accompanying it and never ArcGIS Desktop as well.

Comment: It doesn't output an error. It's running on ArcGIS pro.

Comment: It also works by typing interactively on the ArcGIS python window.

Comment: I've tried removing the try and except block.

Comment: The logic of the script is possibly flawed. You are apply an unchanging layer file to all layers in your map. Do ALL layers have exactly the same schema? You don't explain what the layer file is symbolising by, if its by unique categories and using field X then if the next layer does not have field X it would fail.

Comment: Exactly the same thing is happening. Works from GUI, from notepad. Does not work at all from script in toolbox. Schema is identical.